# android - timer countdown wrong for several runs

Tags: java, android

In my game the user scores, when he sweeps from left to right on the screen within 5 seconds. If he sweeps from right to left or needs more than 5 seconds the game is over.
I'm trying to cancel the countdown after he gets a point to refresh the timer. Also i'm tring to cancel it when the user sweeps wrong. The problem I have is that when the user gets a point, the countdown doesn't stop counting and when there is a fault, so the game should be over, the timer counts down the remaining time from previous run before it stops and print GameOver. Is it wrong to use a global timer?

```
  public class GameScreen extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

        private boolean animationRunning = false;
        public int sco = 0;
        float x1, x2;
        float y1, y2;
        public TextView text;
        public TextView scorete;
        private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";
        CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
            text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            scorete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            scorete.setText(String.valueOf(sco));           
            load();

        }        

        private void load() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) { // adjust the milli
                // seconds here
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    text.setText(""
                            + String.format(
                            "%02d:%03d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                    .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                            .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toMillis(millisUntilFinished)
                                    - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))));

                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    text.setText("GameOver.");

                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();        
        }   

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {      

            switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    x1 = touchevent.getX();
                    y1 = touchevent.getY();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    x2 = touchevent.getX();
                    y2 = touchevent.getY();

                    if (!animationRunning) {
                        // if left to right sweep event on screen
                        if (x1 < x2 && (x2 - x1) >= (y1 - y2) && (x2 - x1) >= (y2 - y1)) {

                                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                                sco++;
                                scorete.setText(String.valueOf(sco));

                                load();
                         }

                              // if left to right sweep event on screen                                                     
                              else if (x1 > x2 && (x1 - x2) >= (y1 - y2) && (x1 - x2) >= (y2 - y1)) {

                                animationRunning = true;                    
                                mCountDownTimer.cancel();                                            
                                text.setText("GameOver.");     

                              }  
                    }

               }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the logic in the if statements are correct? For example, try printing something out in those statements to see if they're even being reached

Comment: It's an excerpt of my program, I hope I didn't summarized it wrong. For me the thing works fine, I only have problems with the timer. It never starts counting anew from 5 seconds when the user scores, but it keeps going down, like it only allows 5 seconds at all

Comment: What happens when you remove `load()` in the case where the user scores? Does the timer stop?

Comment: Then it's just loaded once and is not repeated

Comment: You brought me to an idea, it's working now - thank you!

Comment: I will post my answer anyway just in case it brings more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When restarting a timer, I'd suggest calling `start` instead of re-instantiating the `CountDownTimer` by calling the `load` method.

Change

```
mCountDownTimer.cancel();
sco++;
scorete.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
load();
```

to

```
mCountDownTimer.cancel();
sco++;
scorete.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
mCountDownTimer.start();
```